# Override MessageBox.Show

Tags: c#, overriding, messagebox, citrix

I am seeking to override the `System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show()` method to save modifying a monolithic codebase to use a new messagebox function.

I am using the Citrix Mobility SDK to instrument a legacy C# Windows application to facilitate more intuitive functionality on a mobile device such as iPad or Nexus tablet.

I wish to display a local messagebox on the device, and to do so, I need to replace all calls to `MessageBox.Show` in the application with a `CustomMessageBox.Show` function. The codebase is enormous, and I would rather not modify every file to use `CustomMessageBox.Show` as it would be a large and dangerous job, as well as resulting in tight coupling between the SDK and the application.

Thus, is there a way to override `MessageBox.Show` so that I can reimplement the function for use with this third party SDK, as it would be the most elegant option?

Comment: Something to note is that the Citrix Mobility SDK doesn't give you a generic way to display controls locally on the mobile devices. So you can't use it to show a local message box on a mobile device. There are only a handful of specific APIs in the SDK that allow you to show local controls, e.g. keyboard popup and the show picker APIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot override `MessageBox.Show` because it is a `static` method.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you cannot override `MessageBox.Show`, there is still a solution that would allow it to work for mobile and non-mobile cases.  The easiest way is to create a class that has members that mimic what `MessageBox.Show` can allow.  In this class, it is aware of whether or not mobile is active.  If it is not active, then it uses `MessageBox.Show`.  Otherwise it uses `CustomMessageBox.Show`.  Here is an example member function I have used for error messages in a recent sample.

```
/// <summary>
/// Show a error dialog box
/// </summary>
/// <param name="errorDialogText"></param>
public void ShowErrorDialog(String errorDialogText)
{
    if (!Visible || !IsMobile())
    {
        ErrorDialog.Show(errorDialogText);
    }
    else
    {
        ShowStatus(errorDialogText);
    }
}
```

`ErrorDialog` is a wrapper class for MessageBox.  Note that `IsMobile()` knows that the mobile device is present or not.

```
public class ErrorDialog
{
    //
    // When an exception happens, we show the message here
    //
    public static void Show(String text)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(text, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }

    //
    // When an exception happens, we show the message here
    //
    public static void Show(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.GetType().ToString() + ":" + ex.Message + ex.Source, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }

}
```

This is just abstraction.  By creating a new function, you can wrap the two other functions.  Inside the wrapper function, you can decide which one will be called.  You will still have the pain of updating all the `MessageBox.Show` references but at least it will be under your control and you could change the abstracted function at any time in the future for whatever reason.

My example does not exactly match what you describe. Either you could create the function in the derived Form class or you could create an object and call the function from that object.

I work on the SDK at Citrix and am happy to help.  There are a number of new posts on http://citrixblogger.org that might help out on other issues.